# css/js not loading after changing base url magento 2

Tags: magento2, js-css

I have started working on magento migrating 1.9 to 2.3.0 where I faced the issue of css/js not loading after changing base url. What I want to do is move my local site to live. So obviously base url need to change. So I change this url from admin panel. Next time when I want to open my local magento site, I went to `core_config_data` table and update all `live url` with my `local url`. now all js & css files are missing for frontend as well as admin. actually magento is taking wrong path for all css, it is like`domain_name/version_directory/frontend/` but instead of this the path should be `domain_name/pub/static/version_directory/frontend/`. Search a lot on web but nothing has worked. run too many commands like

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f(f for developer)
clear static directory(except .htaccess)
```

Finally I decide to restore all db backup. but accidentally I `truncate core_config_data` table & voila site is up. then I restore `core_config_data` table from my old backup. I am sure this is not the way & should not follow this method. but just want to know how should it be done? or is it also one of the correct method?

Comment: Might be an issue with virtual theme please set 0(Zero) on current theme table

Comment: `is_featured` and `type`  is `0` for all 3 Magento/blank, Magento/luma,& Magento/backend themes

Comment: Can you please share error screenshot?

Comment: already mentioned in question `magento is taking wrong path for all css, it is likedomain_name/version_directory/frontend/ but instead of this the path should be domain_name/pub/static/version_directory/frontend/`. which is fixed when I truncate `core_config_data` table